# Adding a dependency to an EJB

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, ejb, weblogic

I want to add a dependency to an EJB. How do I do this using Spring? The dependent object is a general service object. Based on code below I want to wire  myDependency without having to use 'new'.
The EJB runs in weblogic.

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "MyBean")
public class MyBean implements MyBeanRemote, MyBeanLocal {

    @EJB(name = "MyOtherBean")
    private MyOtherBean myOtherBean;


    private MyDependency myDependency;
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is well described in the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html?bcsi_scan_554E00F99A9AD604=woTSFmTtXqRlEQJ4mTeLTZbsWeYkAAAAJExjBw==&bcsi_scan_filename=spring-framework-reference.html#ejb-implementation-ejb3):

> For EJB 3 Session Beans and Message-Driven Beans, Spring provides a
>   convenient interceptor that resolves Spring 2.5's @Autowired
>   annotation in the EJB component class:
>   org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.
>   This interceptor can be applied through an @Interceptors annotation in
>   the EJB component class, or through an interceptor-binding XML element
>   in the EJB deployment descriptor.

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class MyFacadeEJB implements MyFacadeLocal {

    // automatically injected with a matching Spring bean
    @Autowired
    private MyComponent myComp;

    // for business method, delegate to POJO service impl.
    public String myFacadeMethod(...) {
        return myComp.myMethod(...);
    }
    ...
}
```

Stateless EJBs and Spring beans, however, offer more or less the same possibilities. Mixing them together seems like unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Thanks for that. Wondering if I can add the dependency without it being a spring bean or if trying to do that points to other design issues? The module that the MyDependency class belongs to is a utility module that is used by other modules. The MyDependency is a util class that calls a 3rd party service.

Comment: Spring is only able to inject Spring beans.

Comment: I ended up replacing MyDependency with a new EJB. This avoided mixing EJBs and Spring components and makes sense since the new EJB provides a separate 'service'.