# Spring MVC: Sharing context between JAR and WAR in EAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Our project is having MDB and WEB in an EAR and need to share the application context.

**web.xml**

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name> 
    <!-- This file is in the root of the EJB JAR file -->
     <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/beanRefContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <!-- This is a bean name in the above XML file -->
    <param-value>ejb-context</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

**beanRefContext.xml**

```
<bean id="ejb-context"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/META-INF/applicationContext.xml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.aer.iheal" />
```

## Problem 1

if we try to load the locatorFactorySelector as `classpath*:beanRefContext.xml` (available under meta-inf of the jar) and read the parentContextKey('ejb-context') bean available in above xml.

We are getting below error

```
 Unable to return specified BeanFactory instance: factory key [ejb-context], from group with resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ejb-context' is defined
```

## Problem 2

to avoid this issue, i have chnaged the param-value of locatorFactorySelector  as  `classpath:/META-INF/beanRefContext.xml`. This time project is getting deployed without any issues. Web application is working fine, but the when we try to use MDB component we facing Null pointer issue.

```
19:03:40,728 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor] (Thread-5 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-4748082)) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
19:03:40,730 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (Thread-5 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-4748082)) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component IHealMDB for method public abstract void javax.jms.MessageListener.onMessage(javax.jms.Message): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:139) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:204) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:306) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentDescription$5$1.processInvocation(MessageDrivenComponentDescription.java:184) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at javax.jms.MessageListener$$$view11.onMessage(Unknown Source) [jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:140) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at $Proxy53.onMessage(Unknown Source)   at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.onMessage(HornetQMessageHandler.java:278)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:983)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:48)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1113)
    at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.aer.iheal.mdb.IHealMDB.onMessage(IHealMDB.java:53) [iHealMDB.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:202) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 37 more
```

On debuging, we can see autowired objects are coming as null.

Any help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem 1

`classpath*:beanRefContext.xml` searches beanRefContext.xml under root folders in all your jars on the classpath. Since you xml is under META-INF folder of the jar, you should use `classpath*:/META-INF/beanRefContext.xml`, or simple `classpath:/META-INF/beanRefContext.xml` if there is only one file existing.

See [Spring classpath prefix difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294423/spring-classpath-prefix-difference)

#### Problem 2

To make auto-wiring works for EJB, need to add below annotation to your EJB:

```
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
```

See [Adding a dependency to an EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318668/adding-a-dependency-to-an-ejb)