# Spring MVC + Hibernate : 2 Tier Application with Spring Annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I want to create 2 tier application (Spring MVC) + (Spring Hibernate).
This is what i want
    web layer: Java EE, Spring
    data access layer: Hibernate, Oracle database

As i am working in Spring MVC latest version, I want to use annotation like @Component/@Autowired/@Bean and Spring configuration, etc in DAL Layer.

But unable to do that.
I am not finding any examples in such kind of scenario in web.

In Microsoft we can do that by
Presentation Layer : ASP.NET
DAL Layer          : Entity Framework

but in JavaEE, I am unable to find how to do that.

Comment: *But unable to do that. I am not finding any examples in such kind of scenario in web.* What about actual spring.io web page? Every module has a short example. Please google first.

Comment: this guides will help you : https://spring.io/guides . Data Jpa with Rest (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) and Restful web service (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) .

Answer (score 0):

For Jboss/Wildfly i am using beanRefContext.xml configuration in resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">

    <!-- The injecting into EJB a spring container context -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath*:spring-configuration.xml">
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

All spring configururation in "spring-configuration.xml"

To injecting spring you need on EJB Controller class setup - @Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
And you can use Spring  @Autowired and other.

Reading [**this aswer and docs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318668/adding-a-dependency-to-an-ejb)